# GDB : changing the assembly code of a running program

Tags: assembly, gdb

I successfuly changed an instruction to a `NOP` since it is pretty basic:

```
set *0x08048e3a = 0x90
```

But I'm trying to change this address `0x08048e3a` which has `je 0x8048e52`. I would like to change it to `je 0x8048ea8`.

But when I do `set *0x08048e3a = 0x74168048ea8` it does not work.
(`0x7416` = `je` instruction)

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`0x74168048ea8` is longer than a word. You should try setting bytes one by one, e.g.

```
  set *(char*)0x08048e3a = 0x74
  set *(char*)0x08048e3b = 0x16
```

etc

Comment: Also note that on x86 the `CALL` and `JMP` instructions are PC-relative (that is, the actual bytes of the instruction encode *offset* from current insruction to the jump target (to be even more precise, offset from the *next* instruction)). Because of that, if you want to `JE 0x8048ea8`, the actual instruction bytes will *not* contain `0x8048ea8`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  I tought that 16 was a part of the "je" instruction. But it was the offset to jump to.

Comment: To save some typing you could set some bytes at once as in set \*(char\*)0x08048e3a@5={0x74,0x16,0x80,0x48,0xea}