# How to step over int with gdb?

Tags: gdb

I'm new to gdb. I've stepped to an `int` instruction as can be seen in the image. Is it possible to step over the `int` instruction? If I use `ni` again it just steps into the interrupt code, where as I want it to run until it returns to `0x7c47`. I'm aware I can just put a breakpoint on that address, but was wondering if there is a single command that does it without a breakpoint?

[image: gdb screenshot]

Comment: You can always patch the instruction over with some "NOP" opcodes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455135/gdb-changing-the-assembly-code-of-a-running-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends.  If by "without a breakpoint" you mean you don't want to use `break` or `tbreak` commands, but you are OK if GDB uses breakpoints behind the scenes, then the `until` command will do what you want.

The `until` command is documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#index-until), the command can take a *locspec* within the current frame, so in your case you'd want:

```
(gdb) until *0x7c47
```

GDB will insert a temporary breakpoint at `0x7c47`, then resume the inferior until the breakpoint is hit.  The breakpoint will then be removed.

If by "without a breakpoint" you literally mean no breakpoints can be used, then I don't think there's a solution.

Comment: I was just after something that removed the breakpoint afterwards, so this is ideal thanks.